# I'm working on the algorithm and it only gives an error in 1 case (Runtime Error)

Tags: swift, algorithm, runtime-error

Only case 4 gives runtime error. I looked at other answers but couldn't find a solution

**[Question](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/circular-array-rotation/problem?isFullScreen=true&h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen)**

I don't return the array. I'm just adding elements

```
func circularArrayRotation(a: [Int], k: Int, queries: [Int]) -> [Int] {
    var result = [Int]()
    
    for i in queries {
        if i < k {
            result.append(a[a.count-k+i])
        }
        else {
            result.append(a[i-k])
        }
    }
    return result
}
```

**Isn't the time complexity of this algorithm O(n). Am I calculating wrong?**

[image: case ss]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`k` can be much larger than the length of the array, so your approach is failing since the index is much larger than the array length.

To correctly handle this, make `k` equal to `k modulus array_length`, since rotating the array by `array_length` times effectively makes no changes to the current ordering.

Comment: Correct.I understand. Swift code: `k % a.count` instead of all `k`